# use Plotly to make the heatmap but have something wrong with the picture

Tags: plotly

when I use **plotly.figure_factory** to make the heatmap ,if the columns are all string is ok：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de7N3.png)

but  when I use the number as a string , something wrong happens:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMIAz.png)

please help me~ thanks all

Comment: your question has been down voted as you have structured your question as images, forcing person who answers to do OCR or type in your code.  post your sample code as markdown not images... make it easier for someone to test and answer

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be something in **plotly** javascript library that behaves differently if trimmed **x** or **y** can be converted to an integer.  Have worked around this by padding **x** and **y** with null character.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z = [[.1, .3, .5],
     [1.0, .8, .6],
     [.6, .4, .2]]

x = [1, 'Team B', 'Team C']
y = [1, 'Game Two', 'Game One']

z_text = z

def hm_axis(l):
    return [f"{chr(0)+str(i)+chr(0)}" for i in l]

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z, x=hm_axis(x), y=hm_axis(y), annotation_text=z_text, colorscale='Viridis')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you; It  really helped me!